# CSS not working in the CSS file but its working when I give styling inside

Tags: html, css

[image][image]

Css not working when I give styling support in the CSS file but its working when I give styling inside need solution

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: Please state the code and errors. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. In addition, the text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Add two parameter to your link code, *rel* and *type*. rel is required.

> rel: Specifies the relationship between the current document and the linked document

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

Comment: my bad rel =stylesheet was missing thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not add a space between the property value and the unit (such as margin-left: 20 px;). The correct way is: margin-left: 20px;